# I couldn't create a Foreign Key in a Table. What should I do?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I have tables named `add_disease` and `specificity_of_gender`. I want to set the primary key of `specificity_of_gender` table as foreign key in `add_disease` table. My codes are like below:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `add_disease`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_disease` (
  `Disease_Id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Disease_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Gender_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Age_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Notion_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Type_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Stage_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Scope_Id` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `Symptoms` text NOT NULL,
  `Description` text NOT NULL,
  `Image` int(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Disease_Id`),
KEY ` Gender_Id ` (`Gender_Id `),
KEY ` Age_Id ` (`Age_Id `),
KEY ` Notion_Id ` (`Notion_Id `),
KEY ` Type_Id ` (`Type_Id `),
KEY ` Stage_Id ` (`Stage_Id `),
KEY ` Scope_Id ` (`Scope_Id `)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
--
-- Dumping data for table `add_disease`
--**
```

And

```
--
-- Table structure for table `specificity_of_gender`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `specificity_of_gender` (
  `Gender_Id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Gender_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Gender_Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `specificity_of_gender`
--

INSERT INTO `specificity_of_gender` (`Gender_Id`, `Gender_Name`) VALUES
(**1, 'Male'),
(2, 'Female'),
(3, 'Others');
```

And MySQL says

```
Error

SQL query:
--
-- Database: `online_medical_service`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `add_disease`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_disease` (
`Disease_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`Disease_Name` varchar( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Gender_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Age_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Notion_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Type_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Stage_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Scope_Id` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Symptoms` text NOT NULL ,
`Description` text NOT NULL ,
`Image` int( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `Disease_Id` ) ,
KEY ` Gender_Id ` ( `Gender_Id ` ) ,
KEY ` Age_Id ` ( `Age_Id ` ) ,
KEY ` Notion_Id ` ( `Notion_Id ` ) ,
KEY ` Type_Id ` ( `Type_Id ` ) ,
KEY ` Stage_Id ` ( `Stage_Id ` ) ,
KEY ` Scope_Id ` ( `Scope_Id ` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1072 - Key column 'Gender_Id ' doesn't exist in table
```

Please can anyone tell me what to do?? please help me with this... :(

Comment: In the future, please enclose your code in code sample blocks (I submitted an edit doing this already.) It greatly enhances the readability of your question so that other users can better help you with your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that you have extra spaces on the `column name` and `index name` when you define an index,

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Disease_Id`),
KEY `bGender_Idb` (`Gender_Id `),
KEY ` Age_Id ` (`Age_Id `),
KEY ` Notion_Id ` (`Notion_Id `),
KEY ` Type_Id ` (`Type_Id `),
KEY ` Stage_Id ` (`Stage_Id `),
KEY ` Scope_Id ` (`Scope_Id `)
```

so basically,

```
`Gender_Id ` is not equal to `Gender_Id`
          ^ see extra spaces from here
```

and you did that to all your columns: `Gender_Id`, `Age_Id`, etc..

**You should remove the extra trailing spaces and it will work.**

Below is a link of the fixed `DDL`

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ba70/1)

Comment: Thank you so much...I'll remove the extra spaces and if I face any problem, I'll let you know... :)